# GLUT Creating a binary / RAW image file

Tags: image, opengl, textures, glut

I have question about creating a binary / raw image file.

I've made an image in photoshop and now I want to load that in a C program.
I followed this tutorial http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html  but I don't know how to convert my own image to a .RAW file.

Can anyone help me out with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Download [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), it is a command-line utility that can convert images into all kind of ways. And it supports many platforms.
So you could save your file in Photoshop to for example a PNG file, then run the following command to convert it to raw grayscale 8 bit:

```
convert MyImage.png -depth 8 gray:MyRawImage.raw
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Save As` and selecting `RAW` from the `format` drop-down. Humorously, it is listed under "P" for `Photoshop RAW`.

I don't know if it is the right kind of RAW which GLUT requires...

Comment: Thnx for the tip but it didn't work :( The RAW file is just a binary file without any headers and any form compression.

Comment: I looked for info on RAW with respect to GLUT, but there's a lot of search noise...

Comment: Yeah indeed, very annoying. I tried with gimp but still no results and I updated my post with the tutorial that I followed. Maybe it gives some extra clues

Comment: This may actually get a quicker answer at gamedev.stackexchange.com. However, your tutorial mentions that any image format will do, but presumably you need a file loader. Probably beyond your current skillset with GLUT, but I see this (for example): http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/mjktips/libtiff/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, with that tutorial code:

1. Open your image in GIMP
2. Go to Layer/Transparency/Remove Alpha Channel. If it's already removed the option will be greyed out, which is fine. If you have
   multiple layers, do this for all of them. (You MUST remove the alpha channel or else GIMP will write RGBA instead of RGB, and you'll just see a repeating lattice pattern instead of your image.)
3. File/Save As... and at the very bottom of the save popup, there's an option "Select File Type (By Extension)" with a (+). Expand it.
4. Select Raw image data
5. At the top of the save popup, manually give your file a .raw extension and save. Click OK to accept the default options.

Then you should be able to save it, move it to your program's directory, and read it in with the code from that tutorial.

Also, to save yourself another headache source, I suggest adding an error message if the file isn't found, like replace the line

```
if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
```

with

```
if ( file == NULL ){
    printf("texture file not found.");
    return 0;
}
```